# copy values of html in a browser

Tags: html, google-chrome, mozilla

How does one copy all the values of the specific elements in the html page?

This image shows what I mean:

[image]

I would like to copy all the values of the `option` element-> **cityOne**, **cityTwo** and so forth. `option` elements are children of the `select` element.

Is it possible to copy just the values in mozilla or chrome?

Comment: It's not possible by default with Firefox's developer tools. There may be an add-on that does this, but software recommendations are off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]it's easy. you just need to know your developer tools and browser console well enough.

first. in your inspector. click on the select-element, then go to your browser console and type in the following code

```
for(var i=0; i<$0.getElementsByTagName("option").length; i++){console.log($0.getElementsByTagName("option")[i].innerText);}
```

$0 refers to the currently selected element in your inspector window.